# Is it possible in the VBA to determine that the text overlaps the cell border?

Tags: vba, text, border

I wont to check if text overlaps the cell border and then depending on the result, make some changes. Is it possible in the VBA to determine that the text overlaps the cell border?

[image: text overlaps the cell border]

Comment: This looks like a good starting point [When does Excel decide to overflow text into adjacent cells, or cut them at the boundary?](https://superuser.com/questions/400498/when-does-excel-decide-to-overflow-text-into-adjacent-cells-or-cut-them-at-the)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about a direct check, but you can try a dirty workaround:

Use the [.ShrinkToFit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-shrinktofit-property-excel) method to check if the text would need to shrink down in order to fit into the cell(s) in question. If it does, it overlaps.